# Unity 2D, объект должен двигаться только после касания триггера, но почему-то движется сразу после запуска мира

Tags: unity3d

```
private AudioSource audioSource;
public Vector2 direct;
public float acceleration; //ускорение, чтобы подогнать под звук
public Rigidbody2D RB;
public bool USE_SOUND; //ставлю если объект должен играть звук
public bool SOUND; //активируется после того как заиграл звук
void Start()
{
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    SOUND = false;
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Player" & USE_SOUND == true)
    {
        audioSource.Play();
    }
    SOUND = true; //звук начался, значит теперь SOUND = true

}
private void Update()
{
    if (SOUND == true) //если TRUE то объект должен начинать движение
    {
        RB.AddForce(direct.normalized * acceleration);
    }
}
```